# Companion software for managing quotes and excerpts

Tags: bibliographies, software

I need to quote and excerpt a lot of the same passages from a diverse library in my work. I'd like to find an app that's basically a purpose-built database for this kind of thing -- where I can store the excerpted text, the BibTeX source, the page number, a brief description, maybe some keywords/tags/categories. Basically something like Jabref, but where elements are passages not sources. I found an app called [TextCite](https://textcite.sourceforge.net/), but it looks like it's no longer being updated and I had some trouble installing it.

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: There is the internet.  Just search for a partial quote and it will probably find the source.

Comment: @ John K: I'm looking to manage excerpts and quotations that I already know and own within printed books in my personal reference library.

Comment: So you want to create a database and somehow access the data via LaTeX.  A flatfile database is easy enough as a comma delimited list.  There are several packages available, but I am only familiar with pgfplotstable and readarray.

Comment: Do you necessarily require a GUI tool or a simple LaTeX approach is also okay? e.g., how BibLaTeX reads data with .bib files.

Comment: If you are okay with the latter, then I would suggest this. Create one example of what you want to see in the output document manually. Without any tools, just use any word processing software and create something as a sample. A paragraph, a citation and whatever else that needs to go with it. If you present what you want to see in the output, it will be much easier to think of automating it.

Comment: You could perhaps just use BibLaTeX:
1. you create standard entries for the full books or articles;
2. you define a custom entry type for excerpts, and link them to the book or articles by means of `crossref` field;
3. you use a field like `annotation` or define some custom field to store your excerpt.
Then, of course, you have to work a bit in order to use the content of the fields. I'm not an expert, but I guess it can be done quite easily. And perhaps you can use Jabref or another app, at least partially, to create and manage your `.bib` file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions all. I was not thinking that the solution would one where my LaTeX code would retrieve and insert the content automatically, but the idea is intriguing.  The greatest functionality I'm looking for is browsing/sorting. For example, "find quotes catagorized as "kittens" and "playing". I'd be fine with a solution where I would copy/paste out of the repository because I only use 3--6 excerpts per project. I *did* get TextCite to run, and I think it'll do what I want, but I'm not jazzed that it's no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

A proof of concept of what I mentioned in my comment (using BibLaTeX, a custom entry type for the excerpts, and `usera` custom field for the text of the excerpt):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{mybook,
  author  = {John Doe},
  title = {The Title},
  publisher = {The Publisher},
  year    = {2023},
},

@custom{myextract,
  crossref = {mybook},
  pages = {200},
  usera = {This is the text of my excerpt}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\citefield{myextract}{usera}, from \textcite{myextract}

\end{document}
```